# how to make the div fill 100% of the width of the screen

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a div colord pink and i want it to be tilted to the right
but when i did it the div didn't take 100% of the width of the sreen.
I also made the body magin and padding 0 but it still doesn't work

```
<html>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="backgroundColor"><div>
</div>
</html>
```

```
<css>
    .body{
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
     }

    .backgroundColor{
       width: 100%;
       height: 160px;
       margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
       background-color: pink;
       transform: rotate(-9deg);
    }
<css>
```

When i did this the top-right and bottom-left corner of the div didn't fill the whole screen.
How can i make the corners fill the whole width of the screen without adding a scrollbar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: what is your expected result? Can you share you demo link?

Comment: html, body { margin: 0; } resets the default margins

Comment: no i mean can i make the div fully touch the sides of the screen not just the bottom-right and the top-left corners without adding a scroll bar at the bottom of the screen

Comment: https://9elements.com/blog/content/images/2020/02/03-4.png something like this but the top-right and bottom-left corners didn't touch the sides of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this html and css

```
<div class="bg"></div>

.bg {
width:100%;
height:300px;
background-color:red;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 39%, 100% 14%, 100% 28%, 100% 45%, 0 68%);
clip-path: polygon(0 39%, 100% 14%, 100% 28%, 100% 45%, 0 68%);}
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid scroll bar, use `style="overflow: hidden;"` on body tag